# Python: place a characters in string

Tags: string, python-2.7

I want:

```
input: 1x output:1*x
input: 2x output:2*x
input: 3x output:3*x
input: 4x output:4*x
input: 5x output:5*x
input: 6x output:6*x
input: 7x output:7*x
input: 8x output:8*x
input: 9x output:9*x
input: )x output:)*x
input: x( output:x*(
```

I tried doing this by .replace but it is too lengthy and heavy.
Can i do this in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python strings are immutable.
 You can't ever modify a string in place. When modifying and assigning it the same name as the original string, you are just creating a new string having some contents of the original string.**

To solve your problem, you can do this.

```
>>> my_input = '1x'
>>> output = my_input[0] + '*' + my_input[1]

>>> output
1*x
```

Here you insert `'*'` between the index 0 and index 1 of the input string.

To understand the immutability of strings, let us see some examples.

**Eg 1:**

```
>>> string1 = 'aacc'
>>> string2 = string1
```

Now we will insert `'bb'` in between the string.

```
>>> string1 = string1[:2] + 'bb' + string1[2:]

>>> string1
aabbcc

>>> string2
aacc
```

Here `string2` still refers to the old `string1`. You haven't actually modified the `string1` but created a new string object.

**Eg 2:**

```
>>> string1 = 'ac'
```

Now let us insert `'b'` in between.

```
>>> string1[1:1] = 'b'     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply.. That worked for me. I used `char_list = ['1x', '2x', '3x', '4x', '5x', '6x', '7x', '8x', '9x', ')x', 'x(']
    for char in char_list:
        if char in valid_text:
            valid_text = valid_text.replace(char, (char[0] + '*' + char[1]))`

Comment: Cool! But one interesting thing to note is that `.replace()` will return a copy of the string with all occurrences of old substring  replaced by new. If it is being referenced anywhere, there it still refers to the old string.

Answer (score 0):

```py
s[0] + "*" + s[1]
"{0}*{1}".format(*s)
"{0}*{1:}".format(*s)
'*'.join(s)

import re
re.sub("^(.)", r"\1*", s)
re.sub("^.", r"\g<0>*", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char_list = ['1x', '2x', '3x', '4x', '5x', '6x', '7x', '8x', '9x', ')x', 'x(']
for char in char_list:
    if char in valid_text:
        valid_text = valid_text.replace(char, (char[0] + '*' + char[1]))
```